# Display column name with shiny renderTable when there is only one column in the table

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app which outputs some tables using renderTable. The user defines how many columns there will be in the output table. If the user defines one output column the column name just says data instead of the actual column name. Is it possible to get the actual column name when only a single column is output using renderTable? See the picture below. If I select a second ratio the column names are displayed.

[image]

Comment: You can try and wrap final `data.frame` object in `data.table()`. One column `data.frame` converts to 1-dimensional object while `data.table` do not and I believe this is an issue here.

Comment: @Dominik Żabiński. Thanks for the suggestion. When I do this I have the same issue except it changes the column header "data" to "V1". Once the second column is selected the actual column names come through same as before.

Comment: ZT_Geo - Please provide an example. @DominikŻabiński you can set `drop = FALSE` to avoid dropping dimensions for matrices, arrays and data.frames. See `?\`[\`` or [this](https://win-vector.com/2018/02/27/r-tip-use-drop-false-with-data-frames/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no code provided please check the following app which displays a single column `data.frame`. As mentioned in the comments you need to make sure to avoid dropping dimensions when subsetting via `drop = FALSE`:

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(
    inputId = "col_count",
    label = "Column Count",
    value = 1L,
    min = 1L,
    max = 5L
  ),
  tableOutput("single_col_tab")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$single_col_tab <- renderTable(iris[1:10, seq_len(input$col_count), drop = FALSE])
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Also please see `` ?`[` `` or [this article](https://win-vector.com/2018/02/27/r-tip-use-drop-false-with-data-frames/).